# How to check if my .vim/buflist.txt file is empty or contains whitespace(s) in _vimrc

Tags: vimrc, gvim, microsoft-windows

How to check if my `.vim/buflist.txt` file is empty or contains whitespace(s) in `_vimrc` of my gVim on Windows 10?

---

I tried this:

```
let BufferListFile = $HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt"

echo BufferListFile

" This function SHOULD return true if the defined
" buffer list file is empty = contains
" either nothing, or white space
" but is does not work

function BufferListFileEmpty()
    return (empty(glob(g:BufferListFile)))
endfunction

if (BufferListFileEmpty())
    echo "Empty"
else
    echo "Not Empty"
endif
```

I always get:

> Not Empty

no matter if the file contains literally nothing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I dont think `empty` works on file contents; rather, it checks if it’s arguments are empty strings or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you found out you are only working with the file name. In order to check the *contents* of the file you can use `readfile()`. It will return a list with all the lines from the file. You can then iterate through the lines in a `:for` loop and check for whatever you want.  Or you can filter the list items with `filter()`. But I think the fastest way is to use `match()`:

```
function! BufferListEmpty()
  let BufferListFile = $HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt"
  let lines = readfile(BufferListFile)    " read the file *contents* into a list
  let matched_index = match(lines, '\S')  " find the first entry with a non-space
  return matched_index == -1              " if no match was found -1 was returned
endfunction
if BufferListEmpty()
  echo "Empty"
else
  echo "Not"
endif
```

You might want to read these help topics:

```
help readfile()
help match()
help filter()
help :for
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the manual:

```
:help empty
```

> empty({expr})                                           empty()
>
> Return the Number 1 if {expr} is empty, zero otherwise.
>
> - A List or Dictionary is empty when it does not have any items.
> - A String is empty when its length is zero.
> - A Number and Float is empty when its value is zero.
> - v:false, v:none and v:null are empty, v:true is not.
> - A Job is empty when it failed to start.
> - A Channel is empty when it is closed.
>
> For a long List this is much faster than comparing the length with zero.

So, it does not work, because `empty` does not check the file contents at all.

<strike>Still, I have not figured out, as to how to do this, if even possible.</strike>

---

## Update

I am now able to determine if the file is completely empty with the following code, I structured it to functions, because they might be handy. This does not solve the problem of whitespace(s) in the buffer list file. So, I will be testing the other solution posted. And if working, accepting it.

```
" This defines the name and path of my buffer list file
let BufferListFile = $HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt"


" This function returns true if the defined
" buffer list file exists
" No matter if it is readable by the user
" Gotten from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23496813/1997354
" Needs verification
function BufferListFileExists()
    return (!empty(glob(g:BufferListFile)))
endfunction


" This function returns true if the defined
" buffer list file is readable by the user
function BufferListFileReadable()
    return (filereadable(g:BufferListFile))
endfunction


" This function returns true if the defined
" buffer list file is completely empty
function BufferListFileEmpty()
    return (getfsize(g:BufferListFile) == 0)
endfunction


" Debugging
echom BufferListFileExists()
echom BufferListFileReadable()
echom BufferListFileEmpty()


if (BufferListFileExists() && BufferListFileReadable() && BufferListFileEmpty())
    echo "Empty"
else
    echo "NotEmpty"
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size of the file using [`getfsize()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getfsize%28%29), but to check if it has whitespace in it, you'll either have to read the file in Vim, or use an external command (like `grep`, or Windows' `find`). Since you have to read the file anyway for the whitespace check anyway, you could perform both checks like so:

```
let BufferListFileContents = readfile(BufferListFile)
let BufferListFileIsEmpty = empty(BufferListFileContents)
let BufferListFileIsWS = ! empty(filter(BufferListFileContents, 'v:val =~ "\\S"'))
```

Where the last line filters out lines containing only whitespace, and then checks if the result list is not empty.